# Why it is required to return *this when this is still being passed?

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, assignment-operator

I have written following class which has overloaded assignment operator. As shown in example everywhere I returned `*this` from assignment operator.

```
class Sample
{
    int *p;
    int q;

public:

    Sample()
    {
        cout<<"Constructor called"<<endl;

        p = new int;
        q = 0;
    }


    Sample& Sample::operator =(const Sample &rhs)
    {
        cout<<"Assignment Operator"<<endl;

        if(this != &rhs)
        {
            delete p;

            p = new int;
            *p = *(rhs.p);
        }

        return *this;
    }

    void display()
    {

        cout<<"p = "<<p<<"     q = "<<q<<endl;
    }
};
```

When I call assignment operator like `a = b`, it goes like, `a.operator=(b);`.

Now I am calling a's operator function, this is already being passed with `operator =` then why it is required to return it from assignment operator?

Comment: It is returned so you can do chaining. Note you don't need to `delete` and then `new` pointer `p`.

Comment: @juanchopanza I got same response everywhere, but did not understand exact meaning

Comment: `a = b;` has the return value `a`. That means you can do `a = b = c = d;`. This is what they call chaining assignments. If you return `void`m  from the assignment operator `a = b` still works, but `a = b = c` does not because `a` gets a `void` and not a `Sample`.

Comment: Result type `T&` is only technically a requirement if you want to use your class as element of a standard container. However, that's a very important reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to return *this (and also by reference) if you want to support chaining of assignment. For e.g

```
Class A
{
};

A x,y,z,w;
x = y = z = w; //For this you are returning *this.
```

EDITED FOR MORE CLARIFICATION:- ( In response to your comment )

Let's suppose you're not returning anything from your assignment operator then expression will be evaluated as follows:-

```
x=y=z  =>   x=(y=z)
```

Above will result into a call to

```
y.operator(z)
```

as assignment operator is right associative.
After this next call would be to

```
x.operator ( value returned from y=z) ).
```

If you don't return any value chaining would fail.

Hope I am clear

Comment: But why? Why can't I support chaining without return *this and that too with reference.

Comment: @pranitkothari And what else would you want the return type and return value of `operator=` to be?

Comment: @pranitkothari Please see my explanation above

Comment: @Angew opps.. looks like I understood something correctly in _wrong way_, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You're returning it to allow for chaining, you can't chain an assignment sequence without returning a reference to `Sample`, perhaps this will make it more clear:

```
int count = 0;

class Sample {
    int *p;
    int q;
    int m_count;
public:
    Sample() {
        m_count = count;
        cout<<"Constructor called for m_count = "<< count++ << endl;

        p = new int;
        q = 0;
    }

    Sample& operator =(const Sample &rhs) {
        cout<<"Assignment Operator (m_count " << 
                    m_count << " = m_count " << rhs.m_count << ") " <<endl;
        if(this != &rhs)
        {
            delete p; // Unnecessary
            p = new int; // Unnecessary
            *p = *(rhs.p);
        }
        return *this;
    }
};
int main() {
  Sample a;
  Sample b;
  Sample c;

  // [b = c] will return a Sample& to the "changed" b
  a = b = c;
}
```

<kbd>[Example](http://ideone.com/9mh7fa)</kbd>

Counter-example with void return value:

```
int count = 0;
class Sample {
    int *p;
    int q;
    int m_count;
public:

    Sample() {
        m_count = count;
        cout<<"Constructor called for m_count = "<< count++ << endl;

        p = new int;
        q = 0;
    }

    void operator =(const Sample &rhs) {
        cout<<"Assignment Operator (m_count " << 
                    m_count << " = m_count " << rhs.m_count << ") " <<endl;

        if(this != &rhs) {
            delete p; // Unnecessary
            p = new int; // Unnecessary
            *p = *(rhs.p);
        }
    }
};

int main() {
  Sample a;
  Sample b;
  Sample c;

  a = b; // Valid
  a = b = c; // Not valid - error: no viable overloaded '='
}
```

Comment: A counter example with an assignment operator returning `void` would make it more clear. Also what are the parenthesis for in `a = (b = c);`?

Comment: @nwp absolutely for not reason if not making my point clear. I'll specify that

Answer (score 1):

An assignment statement,

```
a = b;
```

Requires that `b` should an R-value, and `a` must be an L-value. When you change the assignment as:

```
a=foo();
```

The expression `foo()`, that is the function call to `foo` must result in an R-value. If `foo` returns `void`, it doesn't produce R-value (or any value). Therefore, `foo` is required to return a value (Via a explicit `return` statement(s)). That's the language mandate!

The `b`, in first statement may be L-value also. For example:

```
a = b = c;
```

The variable `b` is both L-value (for `b=c`), as well as R-value (for `a=b`). When `operator=` returns `T&`, it may act as L-value (as well as R-value). But when `operator=` returns `const T&`, it may only be R-value. Therefore, if a class returns a `const` reference, following wont work:

```
a = b = c;
```

Here, `c` is assigned to `a` (in the overload itself), but `b` is a `const` (R-value only). It won't allow `a=b`.

Comment: You're incorrect about the L-value and R-value categorisations. The names started like this, but they have a very different meaning now. It is perfectly possible to assign to an rvalue (of class type), and if the parameter of the assignment is of reference type, an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion never needs to happen on the right-hand side argument.

Comment: @Angew, you are right. We are in C++14 era, but conceptually L-value and R-value are what they are!

Comment: In C++ (since C++11), *lvalues* and *rvalues* are what 3.10 [basic.lval] defines them to be. I consider it quite confusing to use a term for something else than the term's defined meaning.

Comment: @Angew, I respect your knowledge, and you are free to edit the post. :)

Answer (score 0):

Its mainly to support assignment chaining.

```
Sample A,B,C;
A=B=C;
```

*`You can have a look into the existing questions:`*

[Why should the assignment operator return a reference to the object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072169/why-should-the-assignment-operator-return-a-reference-to-the-object)

[Why must the copy assignment operator return a reference/const reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105798/why-must-the-copy-assignment-operator-return-a-reference-const-reference)