# Overloading operators, multiple assignment e.g. a=b=c

Tags: c++, netbeans, operator-overloading

I am having trouble finding a way to enable the assignment operator to do multiple assignments.

given that there is

```
item A,B,C;
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
   C.AddHead(i);
A = B = C;
```

for a single assignment

```
item ::operator=( item &copy)
{
    ...
}
```

How do i write the code for multiple assignment like

```
A=B=C;
```

Comment: the operator should return a reference not a copy. Btw I am sure that there is a duplicate question

Comment: @tobi303 so far i have not been successful finding it

Comment: @Op-Zyra [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072169/why-should-the-assignment-operator-return-a-reference-to-the-object) is relevant.

Comment: As is [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15292892/what-is-return-type-of-assignment-operator). But neither is an exact dupe.

Comment: @InternetAussie I get it now, Thanks

Comment: @StoryTeller Thanks got it